# Nginx proxy pass with rewrite and regex

Tags: nginx

Can Nginx rewrite a URL then use it as a proxy pass?

For example when I visit http://localhost/downloads/example-com/pc.html it should proxy to http://example.com/pc.html

Basically, I want to use my domain to download a file from another website that is why I am doing this

Comment: can you please post your exact use case ?

Comment: @BhavinHirpara, I edited

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can rewrite url and proxy_pass to rewritten url.
But as per what you want to achieve, this simple solution should also work :

```
location ~ /example-com/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/$1;
}
```

if you want you achieve it by rewriting only then you can try following one :

```
location ~ /example-com/ {
   rewrite  /example-com/(.*) /$1 break;
   proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

**UPDATE :**

pass another website url as query param like below :

```
http://yourdomain/downloads/data?data_url=example.com/pc.html
```

and change your nginx configuration as below.

```
location ~ /downloads/data {
    set $data_url $arg_data_url;
    proxy_pass http://$data_url;
}
```

after this configuration change you might get resolver issue as we are passing hostname in proxy_pass at runtime. To solve resolver issue you can follow this link : https://runkiss.blogspot.com/2020/01/using-nginx-authrequest-to-proxy-to.html

Comment: Can we make it dynamic?

Comment: can you pass another website url as query param ?

Comment: Yes we can pass